# WCF Data Services Property Additions Break Client

Tags: .net, wcf-data-services, odata

We have an WCF Data Service with a generated DataServiceClient. We added (not removed) a property to the entity on the server. The client now throws:

```
Type 'OrderIOI' does not have a property named 'total_ioi_qty'


   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.Execute()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext    context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   --- End of inner ExceptionDetail stack trace ---
```

How do we resolve this error? We can't go regenerating client references every time a property is added on the server....(I thought that was the whole point of WCF and Data Contracts)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the DataServiceContext instance, set the IgnoreMissingProperties property to true.